# I want to get all members in discord guild

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to get all members in the Discord guild but I just get the name of my bot.

```py
load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
    GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')
    client = discord.Client()


    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        for guild in client.guilds:
                print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!\n'
                f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})\n')
                members = '\n-'.join([member.name for member in guild.members])
                print(members)
    client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: indentation is pretty much wrong in this question for sure also what error does it raise some kind of error?

Answer (score 1):

If you only get the name of your bot it's probably because you didn't enable **Privileged Gateway intents**. Enable `Server Members Intent` on the [Discord Developer](https://discord.com/developers/applications) site in the **Bot** section.

[image: discord site screenshot]

Then, add this to your code:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

# replace your client with one of these (depends on which one you use):
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="your prefix", intents=intents)
# or
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

---

*You should also fix your indentation. It's really messy.*

Answer (score -1):

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="your prefix", intents=intents)
```

Comment: Hey Basso, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your answer to include any supporting details/explanations which could help others better understand the problem and solution. See [answer] for more information.